# netrw: Pressing "x" on folder name doesn't launch Windows Explorer

Tags: netrw

I am using netrw v171 from Cygwin.  As always, the path of the folder being explored is shown in line 3 of the buffer.  Before v171, I could press `x` when on that line, which would open that folder in Windows Explorer.  Now, all it does is move the cursor to the first item in the folder that is listed first in netrw.  The help for `x` brings me to:

```
CUSTOMIZING BROWSING WITH A SPECIAL HANDLER   *netrw-x* *netrw-handler*
Netrw determines which special handler by the following method:
if g:netrw_browsex_viewer exists, then it will be used...
```

My `g:netrw_browsex_viewer` is set to `cygstart`, which *should* launch Windows Explorer.  In fact, if I yank the folder path in order to issue the following, it *does* launch Windows Explorer:

```
:!cygstart /The/Folder/Path
```

***Why might pressing `x` on line 3 not do the same?***

As per *romainl's* suggestion, I have reported this on [GitHub](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/13687).

Comment: Use the issue tracker.